# Fetch records that does not exists in collection in given array - mongodb

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of student ids.

I want to get those records that were not found from the given array.

Students array:

```
var studentIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Records in collection:

```
[{_id: 1, name: 'John'}, {_id: 4, name: 'mike'}]
```

Now the desired output I require is:

```
[2, 3, 5]
```

What I have tried so far which is not providing the right response:

```
Students.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: { "$nin": studentIds },
            status: "active"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            "idnotIntheArray": {$push: "$_id"}
        }
    }
]);
```

Can anyone find what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You specified `status: "active"` in your query while none of your provided sample data has such fields. Therefore, it is expected to have 0 records returned.

Comment: @ray actually the original dataset is way different. Status is just a flag in collection where I only query those studentIds who are active. So please ignore that

Answer (score 0):

Query

- one way to do it is to create a new collection with 1 document with that array
- unwind that array
- and then lookup with the other collection(the students), if no match => id not found so we keep that id

*The above solution is for MongoDB < 5.1, if you have MongoDB 5.1 +
you dont need to insert data to the collection, you can start from an empty collection and you can use this as first stage
`{ $documents: [{"studentIds": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}] },`

You can test it online in [Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=626884f98b39bcf74dae275d)

Collections (2 collections "array" and "students")

```
[
 "array",
 [{"studentIds": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}],
 "students",
 [{"_id": 1, "name": 'John'}, {"_id": 4, "name": 'mike'}]
]
```

Query
("array" is the collection you created with 1 document, with the array)

```js
array.aggregate(
[{"$unwind": "$studentIds"},
 {"$lookup": 
   {"from": "students",
    "localField": "studentIds",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "results"}},
 {"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$results", []]}}},
 {"$group": {"_id": null, "not-found-ids": {"$push": "$studentIds"}}}])
```

Results

```js
[{
  "_id": null,
  "not-found-ids": [
    2,
    3,
    5
  ]
}]
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to be working

Comment: it works, you can try the example online, produces the expected output,if you create the collection and insert the array.you start the aggregation from that collection you created.

Comment: Well I am unable to see any response from your query in your provided play ground: https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=626884f98b39bcf74dae275d

Comment: queries are auto run(to avoid the need for buttons,other way to run it is with double click there is option), you put the cursor in each stage end to see what stage does, or in the end of the query to see what all the query does, but you have a point, for new people it would be better to auto-run on load.